# Using siunitx to display confidence intervals?

Tags: siunitx

Is there a native way of using `siunitx` to display the confidence interval of a value without using a separate calls of `siuntix` separate definition.

I am doing something like this at the moment, which seems verbose, and isn't too readable:

```
\SI{107205}{meters} (\SI{99}{\% CI} \SIrange{83000}{138400}{meters})
```

This would result in something like:

```
107205 meters (99% CI 83000 meters - 1384000 meters)
```

Comment: You can always define your `\SIci` macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to section 5.4 of the [`siunitx` package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx):

> input-open-uncertainty In some fields, it is common to give the
>   uncertainty in a  number in brackets input-close-uncertainty after the
>   main part of the number, for example ‘1.234(5)’. The opening and
>   closing symbols used for this type of input     set as
>   `input-open-uncertainty` and `input-uncertainty-signs`. Alternatively,
>   the uncertainty may be given as a separate part following a sign.
>   Which signs are valid for this operation is determined by the
>   `input-uncertainty-signs` option. As with other signs, the combination
>   `+-` will automatically be converted to `\pm` internally.
>
> 9.99(9) 9.99(9)
>
> 9.99(9)
>
> 123.0(45)
>
> 12.3(60)

```
\num{9.99(9)} \\  \num{9.99 +- 0.09} \\  \num{9.99 \pm 0.09} \\  \num{123> +- 4.5} \\  \num{12.3 +- 6}
```

Of course, you can always set your own macro (see section 4.5 of the package documentation), as stated by egreg... something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\SIci[5]{\SI{#1}{#2} ({#3}CI: \SIrange{#4}{#5}{#2})}

\begin{document}
The sample was \SIci{89}{\metre}{99\%}{80}{99}
\end{document}
```

Where the output would look:

[image]

By all means, please feel comfortable to change whatever you want with your macro.  I'm sure this is probably not the best way to do it, but it seems to work just fine.  If you have any further questions, please don't hesitate to post another question on the site :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm not looking for displaying it as uncertainty. Perhaps a macro is the best way to go.

Comment: @shootingstars Updated answer, please check if the macro works for you